# Shared Memory sometimes not null terminatied

Tags: c, memory-leaks, shared-memory

```
// reading                        
if((shmid = shmget(key, 0, 0)) < 0) {                  
    perror("shmget");                
    exit(50); 
}                                                         

// attach                                                 
if((data = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0)) == (char *) -1) {        
    perror("shmat");                                      
    exit(100);                                            
}

// get memory size
struct shmid_ds shm_info;
size_t shm_size;
int shm_rc;
if((shm_rc = shmctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, &shm_info)) < 0)
    exit(101);
shm_size = shm_info.shm_segsz;
```

Sometimes data is not null terminated and calling strlen(data) causes segfaults...

So I was trying to make sure that it is null terminated by making

```
data[shm_size] = '\0';
```

But now sometimes it fails on that line of code.

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Thanks for your support! I think after your explanation about the strlen() + 1 == shm_size I have changed the rest of my code not posted here and seems to be fine. I'm waiting for new segfaults and hopefully I will not get any ;)

Comment: show me how you defined and allocated space for the `data`. problem caused by a incorrect memory allocation i guess. you probably need +1 bytes more space for `data` array.

Comment: Yes, you're calling string functions on things that aren't strings. There's the first problem, which suggests you need to read a lot more before you begin tackling the rest of this issue.

Comment: The shared memory is being populated by PHP using shmop... and I'm sure that it contains strings, because when I'm checking the core dump with gdb I can see the contents of data...

Comment: can you see the size too? GDB may only show you the amount of data you specified (like x/3xb gives you only 3 byte). even the "print" function may not always check the size of the string but prints to the '\0' character, which may be accidently after your "string" and so it seems, it is NULL terminated.

Comment: No, after making gdb> set print elements 0, in the end of the text I can see address xxx out of bounds error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[shm_size]` is one beyond the end. You should, instead, do `data[shm_size-1]`, and only if `shm_size != 0`.

But nevertheless, calling `strlen()` makes only sense if you really have put a string inside it. Otherwise, it might return any value `< shm_size` if there happens to be a `\0` character.

Comment: If everything is OK with the shared memory and it is null terminated, shouldn't strlen(data) == shm_size?

Comment: @edo888 No. If the memory area is uninitialized, it might contain any random garbage which might, as written, contain \0 chars which stop the counting.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are `0`-origin, you want:

```
data[shm_size - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Making that, it uses 100% CPU always... Please note that my code works like a charm almost always... But there are cases when it segfaults...

Comment: @edo888: be sure that shm_size is greater than zero. if it becomes zero, that might be the reason of 100% CPU usage.

Comment: If everything is OK with the shared memory and it is null terminated, shouldn't strlen(data) == shm_size?

Answer (score 3):

first: the memory has not to be null terminated. it is undefined at the beginning.
you might want to consider using

```
memset(data,0,shm_size);
```

and second:

```
data[shm_size] = '\0';
```

is wrong by one index. arrays begin at zero so you should use

```
data[shm_size-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Memory is always populated. I'm just reading from it. If everything is OK with the shared memory, shouldn't strlen(data) == shm_size?

Comment: shm_size would be strlen(data)+1 because you have the '\0' character in the end.

Comment: @edo888: Memory is not always populated, and you have no control over whether there is memory past the end of your shared memory block or what that memory would contain. Reading from it (e.g. via `strlen`) is undefined behavior. Yes the contents of a new shared memory buffer will initially be all-zeros, but you're not asking about the contents of the buffer; you're asking about the contents of memory immediately past the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment of the null termination character:

```
data[shm_size] = '\0';
```

is writing past the end of the allocated memory, which is **undefined behavior**.  If it the buffer has character data of length `shm_size`, then it will be necessary to copy it to another buffer in order to null terminate it.

Comment: If everything is OK with the shared memory and it is null terminated, shouldn't strlen(data) == shm_size?

Comment: No, the only way `strlen(data)` could return `shm_size` is if you've invoked undefined behavior, e.g. by calling `strlen` on a buffer that's not null terminated. Like all string buffers, you need to account for the null termination when choosing the buffer length.

Answer (score 2):

By doing

```
`data[shm_size] = '\0';`
```

you're actually accessing a memory region **outside** the bounds of the shared memory ... the `data[index_value]` syntax on a pointer pointing to a raw memory block is the same as saying

```
*(data + index_value*sizeof(unsigned char))
```

Thus `data[0]` will dereference and return the value at the first memory address in the shared memory segment, and `data[shm_size]` will do the same at and address past the end of the shared-memory segment.

Comment: If everything is OK with the shared memory, shouldn't strlen(data) == shm_size?

Comment: No, because `strlen()` does not include the NULL-terminating value.  Thus the actual *minimum* size of a memory block needed to store a zero-terminated string needs to be equal to `strlen() + 1`.